# Creating a custom tomcat Http11Protocol for SSL to decrypt encrypted keystore/truststore passwords

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, encryption, customization

I created a custom Http11Protocol to override the behaviour of Tomcat Connector for SSL to be able to decrypt encrypted keystore/truststore passwords, but i'm not able to access the Connector's attributes (e.g. keystorePass):

```
    public class CustomHttp11Protocol extends Http11Protocol {`
      public CustomHttp11Protocol(){    
        super();
// Decrypt keystore/truststore passwords and set them to the super class (Http11Protocol)
...
      }
    ////
    }
```

Server.xml:

```
<Connector port="4443" protocol="x.y.CustomHttp11Protocol"   connectionTimeout="20000" 
SSLEnabled="true"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
clientAuth="true"
sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreType="PKCS11"
keystorePass="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
truststoreFile="NONE"
truststoreType="PKCS11"
truststorePass="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

We're still use Tomcat 6.0.33 (right now it's not possible to switch to a Tomcat's newer version).

Do you have any suggestion please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you intend to set/access the attributes *in the constructor*? Naturally none of the setters will have been called yet, as the object is currently being constructed. I'm just looking at this class's javadoc, and it has `init()` and `start()` and other methods that seem to be lifecycle related - I assume that you won't be happy with accessing anything in the constructor - instead find the right time in its lifecycle and override/customize that code.

Comment: I thougth that the Connector is initialized first with the attributes and i could access these attributes from my custom Http11Protocol (the default constructor). It works thank you.

Comment: Well, nothing is ever being set on an object if that object has not been constructed before...